# How to make two rows in header of jTable

Tags: java, jtable, rows

I want to make table in Java with two rows in header, like this:

[image]

For this reason I have proceed with this code:

[image]

But I don't have a good result, please help me.

Comment: Do not post images - post code.  Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Ok, I will ask my problem without images, thank you